# Alterar Href com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando copiar o href da class buy-button para .teste, porém  alterando o "redirect=true" para false.

Consigo apenas copiar, mas não alterar o redirect. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<a class="buy-button" href="/checkout/cart/add?sku=17839&amp;qty=1&amp;seller=1&amp;redirect=true&amp;sc=1" style="display:block">EU QUERO</a>
<a class="teste" href=""><p> Botao </p></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tentou um simples `replace`? Considerando que já tenha obtido a URL:

```
var url = "/checkout/cart/add?sku=17839&amp;qty=1&amp;seller=1&amp;redirect=true&amp;sc=1";
url = url.replace("redirect=true", "redirect=false");
seulink.href = url;
```

Comment: assim fica mais simples, mas perde o ar da magia javascript kkk (brinks)

Comment: @bfavaretto seria exatamente isso, acabei esquecendo do replace, funcionou certinho.

Comment: kkkkkkk sim Tafarel

Comment: Ô @Tafarel minha resposta acabou aceita e eu perdi a chance de dizer "vai que é tua!" :)

Answer (score 1):

Vê se é isso que você deseja.

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}
```

Modo de usar:

```
var newUri = updateQueryStringParameter("minhaurl.com?updateIsto=true","updateIsto",false);
```

Créditos: [SO - En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter#answer-6021027)